# Return a list that's already been named in python 3.3

Tags: python, list, return

I'm trying to return something from a function but I keep on getting an error saying that scoreDict isn't defined, well the code should explain what I'm trying to do..

```
names = ['joe','tom','barb','sue','sally']
scores = [10,23,13,18,12]

def makeDictionary(names, scores):
    scoreDict = dict(zip(names, scores))
    return scoreDict

print(scoreDict)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know I'm doing something horribly wrong, but I can't figure out how to do it! I've searched a bit in google but couldn't find what I need.

Comment: To clarify, I have tried to do print(makeDictionary(names, scores)).. Which gets me the result needed, but if I want to modify the scoreDict that wouldn't work with that right? Like, lets say I want to return Barb and her score.. Or I want to add someone to the list with their score.. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **call** that function, else its body never executes!

Moreover, you need to **assign** its result -- it doesn't get done implicitly.

So, add

```
scoreDict = makeDictionary(names, scores)
```

before trying to `print` said `scoreDict` (or do anything else with it:-).

Comment: The problem when I do that is.. I would have to do print(makeDictionary(names, scores)).. Which gets me the result needed, but if I want to modify the scoreDict that wouldn't work with that right? Like, lets say I want to return Barb and her score.. Or I want to add someone to the list with their score.. etc.

Comment: Even though you are absolutely right, this usage may easily confuse him. It looks like he is very new to programming and I think a better approach would be to explain function scopes. :)

Comment: @Fadi, no!  **Assign** the result of calling `makeDictionary` to `scoreDict`, exactly as I showed!, and then you can print it, modify it, use it any way you want.  You just need to **call** the function and **assign** is result, **exactly** as I said: please re-read my answer, it is not long, and follow it carefully!

Comment: @ozgurv good luck explaining deep theory to somebody "very new to programming" rather than directly addressing their practical problem.  Actually got me married to the most wonderful woman in the world, who was just asking me for practical help on using `somelist.append` in Python -- and is now, 15 years later, a best-selling co-author of a Python book, and the only woman winner of the Frank Willison Award for contributions to the Python community -- but then, I **am** singularly lucky, plus, I'm not looking to get married again anyway:-)

Comment: I'd definitely try that if the questioner was female.

Comment: Well thank you Alex! And I'm not very new to programming, just new to python, also I'm a quick learner! Oh and don't worry I do have a girlfriend! :P

Answer (score 2):

You did not call the function, so the variable `scoreDict` is not defined in the current scope :

```
names = ['joe','tom','barb','sue','sally']
scores = [10,23,13,18,12]

def makeDictionary(names, scores):
    scoreDict = dict(zip(names, scores))
    return scoreDict

scoreDict = makeDictionary(names, scores)
print(scoreDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Alex Martelli says, you have to call the function. An example of a way to fix this would be replacing the `print(scoreDict)` line with `print(makeDictionary(names, scores))`